What's that supernatural film with something under grey tunnels?
I saw briefly some footage from an amazing film and I want to identify and watch it in full.
It's set (maybe) in some middle eastern location and there is a monster (?) under the earth. It has extraordinary music - haunting and classy - as soldiers slowly move through tunnels to find it, then one is suddenly sucked into a vault. Then you see a great shot looking up from the bottom of the 'vault' up to the small window that's semi-open. The vault seems to be made of concrete and its massive. The film has the style of a Friedkin film like The Sorcerer.  

You're looking for The Keep(1983).

Within an uninhabited citadel (the “Keep” of the title) in World War II-era Romania lies entrapped a dangerous demonic entity named Radu Molasar (Michael Carter). The inner walls of the citadel contain 108 T-shaped icons, supposedly made of nickel. When the German Army under the command of Capt. Klaus Woermann (Jürgen Prochnow) occupies the castle to control the Dinu Mountain Pass following the commencement of Operation Barbarossa, Molasar is unleashed by a pair of looting soldiers who identify one glowing icon as being made of silver. In the ensuing days, Molasar kills several soldiers. A detachment of Einsatzkommandos under the command of sadistic SD Sturmbannführer Eric Kaempffer (Gabriel Byrne) then arrives to deal with what is thought to be partisan activity, executing villagers as collective punishment.

Here is the trailer.



